# Children in function e?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="home">
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>

#home {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#second {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}

$(window).click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == 'home'){
       alert('This is div home!');
    }

});
```

Now if i click on green div then this doesnt working, but this div is  in div red.
Is possible automatically add all children div id home for this? If this div have 100 children then i have must add 100 if?

Comment: Just `$( '#home' ).on( 'click', function () { ... });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to check if the target element is within the `#home` div:

```
$(document).click(function(e)
{
    if(e.target.id == 'home' || $(e.target).closest('#home').length)
    {
       alert('This is div home!');
    }
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6sY49/

Comment: +1, Also you can use `e.target.parentNode.id === 'home'` instead of `$(e.target).parent('#home').length`. IMO it's simpler, easier to read, and it's definitely a lot faster.

Comment: @user1 - That would only check the parent node, not all the ancestors. I replaced `parent` in my code with `closest`.

Comment: I believe that's what he wanted, because he said children, not descendants. But it could be that he wants all descendants too. BTW, the left half of your or clause is unnecessary now, because closest includes the current element. See the differences between closest and parents here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @user1 - Wow. Didn't know that also includes the current element. Learn something new every day! However, I'm leaving it as is for now, since no one here is sure what exactly it is the OP wants. Once he clarifies, I'll fix it either way.

Comment: @JosephSilber Just this: `if ( $( e.target ).closest( '#home' )[ 0 ] )`. The `closest` method will stop (and select) if the `e.target` element itself has that ID.

Comment: This has already been pointed out to me by @user1. See my reply to that comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `e.target` will always be the most deeply nested element.

If you need to test all ancestors, then loop through the ancestors using `.parentNode`.

```
$(window).click(function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    while(el.id !== 'home') {
        el = el.parentNode;
    }

    if( el ) {
       alert('This is div home!');
    }
});
```

---

But it seems like you're trying to do document wide event delegation. jQuery has this ability built in.

```
$(document).on('click','#home',function() {
    alert('This is div home!');
});
```

Or before **jQuery 1.7**:

```
$(document).delegate('#home','click',function() {
    alert('This is div home!');
});
```

Comment: I think he wanted children only, not descendants. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @user1: Yeah, it's tough (for me) to understand the question. But since an `e.target` won't have any child elements, I assumed OP was trying to get to the one with the `home` id, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for mentioning on and delegate :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you would just want to use

```
$('#home').click(function(e) {
    alert('This is div home');
});
```

this'll use the event bubling & be a lot more efficient!